# weird automatic wp redirection

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

When I type the url address of my website **with www** for example `http://www.mayumibeats.com/question` it would redirect me to my homepage which is `http://mayumibeats.com/` but when i type it **without www** on it for example `http://mayumibeats.com/question` it just works fine. 
What am I missing here?

Here is my `.httaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

**NOTE:** The site is wpmu

Comment: It would help to show your .htaccess file.

Comment: Can we see your htaccess file

Comment: attached now is my .htaccess file

Comment: I think there is problem with your site url , can you paste here what is your site url ?

Comment: http://mayumibeats.com/ is my site url

Answer (score 0):

Try changing site URL and home URL, replace `http://mayumibeats.com` with `http://www.mayumibeats.com`